# How to edit font size of product title in catalog page

Tags: magento2, development, fonts

I need to edit the font for the product titles in the catalog page. I believe it is referenced by "**product-item-link**" or "**product-item-name**" ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow below steps:-

1 Create new file catalog_category_view.xml in vendor/module/view/frontend/layout.

2 In catalog_category_view.xml add css file like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
         <css src="Vendor_Module::css/style.css"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

3 Create style.css file in vendor/module/view/frontend/web/css/.

4 In style.css, to change font-size add below code:

```
.product-item-details .product-item-name .product-item-link{
  font-size: 20px !important; // whaterver font size you want
}
```

5 Run commnad php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy(add -f for magento 2.2)

6 Flush the cache and try again.